# Alternative for Swenson condensed milk. I'm diabetic

Tags: substitutions, milk

I'm diabetic. I've been given a receipt for ice box pie that uses this milk.  What can I use to replace it with less sugar than receipts shown? It's made with Kool-Aid and cool whip.

Comment: Welcome! Can you post the full recipe and method?

Answer (score 1):

There are actually many recipes for making your own sugar-free or low-sugar sweetened condensed milk. They generally involve combining non-fat milk or powdered milk and water with a sugar substitute like Splenda. Alternately, if it's sufficiently low in sugar, you can add Splenda or another no-calorie sweetener to evaporated milk.

We don't share recipes here but I encourage you to find one that works for you with your preference of milk product and sugar substitute.